# csv. file reading c++...cant read first number in each row

Tags: c++, file, csv

I'm trying to read a .csv file that has multiple rows of numbers.  I understand how to read each value by using the comma delimiter but i seem to have an issue reading the first number in each row.  After looking over my code i now know its because the last number in each row is not followed by a comma which causes the program to skip the first number on the next row.  Is there a way to get around this issue without inserting a comma at the end of each row manually in the file?  I have tried adding reading each individual line separately and then parsing that but reading each line seems to instead read the entire file

Comment: Please post some code.  What function are you using to read the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you know how to split up the string by the comma delimiter, you should also find it easy to split up the string by the end-of-line delimiter.  Then apply a second split process to each of these strings by the comma delimiter.  Also, make sure that your end-of-line delimiter is not causing the problem in the first place, i.e., `"\n"`, `"\r"` and `"\r\n"` are three possible values of the end-of-line delimiter, and one vs. another may be causing the issue of not reading line-by-line in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Substituting "\r" in for "\n" fixed the problem. Does \r always refer to end of line and \n to end of file? I'm relatively new to c++

Comment: `"\r"` and `"\n"` are "carriage-feed" and "line-return" characters from typewriter days, but are used in different ways on different operating systems (Windows, Mac, Linux).  So the source of your file (i.e., the OS where it was created/edited) is an important consideration when coding to handle the different possibilities.

Comment: makes sense, thanks.  last problem: I assume this is some type of syntax problem but i cant seem to split up the line i am reading.  This is what im trying to do:

while (file.good())
    {
        getline(file,line, '\r');
        
        for (i=0; i<=13; i++)
        {
            //getline ( line, hours,',');
            istringstream (hours) >> dailyhours;
            array[i]=dailyhours;
            dailyhours=0;
            totalhours=totalhours+array[i];
            cout << array[i]<< "  ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    file.close();
    cout << totalhours << "\n";

Comment: There are lots of difficulties I have with your comment, first among them is that I cannot tell which of your lines are commented out.  Secondly, I believe that there is a difference in the compiler's interpretation of `'\r'` and `"\r"`, though I am not certain of that.

Comment: I/m sorry about that.  None of the lines are commented out so you can ignore any //.  Also, the getline function causes the building of the code to fail when i attempt to compile with "\r" instead of '\r'.  Is this a result of the variable im using being a string? And the error im getting with the above code "no matching function for call to getline". This is refering to the second getline in the code

Comment: The error in your second call arises because `getline(string, string, string)` is a different call from `getline(file, string, string)`.  You will have to either overload the function `getline` to have two different signatures, or change it to only receive string inputs.